# Mysqli não exibe resultados

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho a seguinte tabela no bd DUELOS , inseri os dados porem na hora de pegar o resultado estou tendo problem o que deve ser?

dados fravados na tabela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo que busca os dados

```
$iddesafiante = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$desafiante = $_SESSION['username'];
$iddesafiado = $_GET['idd'];
$desafiado = $_GET['d']; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM duelos WHERE status='desafiado' AND desafiado='$desafiante' ";
 $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
 while ($dados = $query->mysqli_fetch_array()) {
 echo "Você foi desafiado por: ' . $dados['iddesafiado'] . ' <br> Aceitar Desafio / Não aceitar";
 }
```

erro gerado
          `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::mysqli_fetch_array`

codigo da pagina completo

> ```
>   <?php
>     require_once("functions.php");
>     require_once("config2.php");
>     session_start();
> ```

```
    if (logged_in() == false) {
        redirect_to("login.php");
    }

    //values to be inserted in database table
    $time = time();
    $acao = $_GET['acao'];
    $iddesafiante = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $desafiante = $_SESSION['username'];
    $iddesafiado = $_GET['idd'];
    $desafiado = $_GET['d'];
    $status = 'desafiado';

    switch($acao)
    {
        case 'nenhuma';
           // ---------------- VERIFICACAO SE FOI DESAFIADO------------------
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM duelos WHERE status='desafiado' AND desafiado='$desafiante' ";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    while ($dados = $query->mysqli_fetch_array()) {
      echo "Você foi desafiado por: ' . $dados['iddesafiado'] . ' <br> Aceitar Desafio / Não aceitar";
    }

        break;

        case 'desafiar';
           // ---------------- VERIFICACAO SE JA DUELOU NAS ULTIMAS 24 HORAS COM O MESMO OPONENTE ------------------

           // ---------------- SE NAO DUELOU DESAFIAR ------------------


        break;

        case 'aceitar';
                // ---------------- UPDATE ACEITAR ------------------

        break;

        case 'emduelo';
      echo " breve";
        break;
        case 'breve';
            echo 'verificar se tem desafio';
        break;
        case 'aguardando';
            echo 'vreve';
        break;

        default;
        echo 'texto quando nao existir o parametro';
        break;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: tenta trocar `$dados['iddesafiado']` por `$dados[5]` e `$query->mysqli_fetch_array()` por `$query->fetch_array()`

Comment: alterei sem sucesso

Answer (score 1):

Está invocando um método inexistente:

> while ($dados = $query->**mysqli_fetch_array**()) {

Corrija para

```
while ($dados = $query->fetch_array()) {
```

Claro que não quer dizer que trará o resultado que espera pois o modo como está gerando a query de consulta pode ser inconsistente e inseguro.

Verifique também se a query está sendo formada corretamente.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM duelos WHERE status='desafiado' AND desafiado='$desafiante' ";
```

Crie um simples breackpoint para verificar como está sendo montada a query.

Exemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM duelos WHERE status='desafiado' AND desafiado='$desafiante' ";
echo $sql; exit;
```

Isso imprimirá na tela a query e interromperá a execução da página. Isso é apenas para depurar e encontrar o problema. Isso pode ser chamado de breakpoint.

O que deve fazer? Apenas leia a query e avalie se está correta.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in linha 28 = echo "Você foi desafiado por: '.$dados['desafiante'].' <br> Aceitar Desafio / Não aceitar";   !!! adicionei o echo $sql; exit; e mesmo assim nao mostrou nada

Comment: Nos comentários que fizeste, dá para perceber que existem diversos outros erros, não necessariamente relacionados com o problema descrito na pergunta. São problemas diversos que tornam a questão ampla demais. O problema principal referente ao Mysqli está resolvido. Outros problemas epecíficos, abra uma nova pergunta ou pesquise no site se não tem pergunta semelhante.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira que eu estava utilizando é a seguinte :

```
while ($a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec)) { // fetch_assoc obtendo todos os resultados do banco de dados conforme a consulta
                foreach ($a as $i => $rows) {
                    echo $rows = $a[$i] . "<br/>";
                    $i++;
                }
            }
```